# Elixir Ecto : multiple joins and reusable/composable queries

Tags: join, orm, dependencies, elixir, ecto

In Ecto you can make reusable/composable queries like so :

```elixir
defmodule AModel
  #...
    
  def anonymous(q), do: q |> where([am], is_null(am.user_id))
  end
end
```

See more examples [on this blog post](http://blog.drewolson.org/composable-queries-ecto/).

However, I face a problem using multiple joins.

Let's suppose we have a schema that looks like this :

- AModel belongs to BModel
- BModel belongs to CModel
- CModel belongs to DModel

The solution proposed in this article does not really work with deep joins :

```elixir
q = DModel
  |> join(:inner, [dm], cm in assoc(dm, :c_models))
  |> join(:inner, [_, cm], bm in assoc(cm, :b_models))
  |> join(:inner, [_, _, bm], am in assoc(bm, :a_models)) 
  |> AModel.anonymous
```

Querying functions take as first (second for join) argument a binding table.
It contains the previous joins and is sadly tight to join order.

In our case, the `anonymous` function target the starting table.
However in the query example, AModel is the 4th binding ...

Any idea or technic to get rid of this order dependency ?

**EDIT :**

I get an answer from the blog author.
He told me that there is no native other way to handle bindings than by position in the table.
He also gave [this article](http://www.glydergun.com/a-bit-about-bindings/) highlighting this fact.

But for god sake, if order only matter, why I can't create above it a naming mapping that associates name with binding index ?

Is this too much to ask :p ?

Comment: One of Ecto creators here. This is actually a very hard problem to solve because as long as we make names binding, the chance of conflicts increase greatly, specially because we love to use shortcuts, like you used am, bm and so on. But we know the current affair is also an annoyance, we just don't have a good solution for it (yet).

Comment: I was thinking to try to create an overlay above the binding list.
When making the `join` I can give a symbol name that match the binding position.
Then using the `where` I can extract the required binding providing the name. Do you think it's currently possible to create such mechanic ?
I was thinking using monad-like function that would return {query, binding_names} ...

Comment: I don't think you will be able to achieve it without changing Ecto. You can give the position, I think, as in `def anonymous(q, pos), do: q |> where([am: pos], is_null(am.user_id))` but that's worse IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use named bindings

Ecto 3.0 added [named bindings](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#module-named-bindings) for this use case.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe create some [junction tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)?

---

EDIT: I can see that perhaps I was a bit too terse. I mean to say that you can build junction tables on the backend and then query them.  That way you don't need to worry about building the joins in your Ecto code.  I hope that makes my answer a bit clearer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the edit. However this means : a) duplicate/alter data schema to solve a programmatic problem, sounds wrong. b) It can really afford it due to data size

Comment: Well you did ask for ideas. :)  I agree that duplicating data isn't ideal but if it's between that and writing obtuse, complex code I'll take denormalization any day of the week.

Comment: Yea, no problem. Your answer can work for some case ;) However I hope some one will come with something at code level that can remove the join order dependency. I can't believe this library blocks on such usual use case.